# Message: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:
```

`Message:` The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded
Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `album...', Array)
#3 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(156): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `album...')
#4 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(823): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('albums', NULL)
#5 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(862): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata()
#6 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(969): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()
#7 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php(100): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info()
#8 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php(78): Zend_Db_Table_Select->setTable(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Albums))
#9 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1005): Zend_Db_Table_Select->__construct(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Albums))
#10 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1303): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->select()
#11 /var/www/zf-tutorial/application/controllers/IndexController.php(14): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll()
#12 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): IndexController->indexAction()
#13 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#14 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#15 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#17 /var/www/zf-tutorial/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

`Request Parameters`:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

what i can do please Help me ?

Comment: You didn't notice the 20 bold text in the preview panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the PDO module for your database engine, using PECL. For example:

```
pecl install pdo
pecl install pdo_mysql
```

And load the extensions in your php.ini file, by adding these lines:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: :) Firstly i install sudo apt-get install php-pear after that i try pecl install pdo but not able to install error got harsh@harsh-3000:~$ pecl install pdo
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user

Comment: Try running pecl install with sudo as well. "not writable by the current user" suggests a lack of privileges.

Comment: Oldskool :) I am trying with Sudo only but not able to do that

Comment: configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/PDO_MYSQL/configure' failed

Comment: if you are on a Debian system you should be able to apt-get install a debian packaged pdo driver. I'm not on my debian system so I can't suggest package name, but it is probably something like php-pdo

Answer (score 0):

apt-get should be good for this, and as I recall the PDO version is in the php5-mysql package:

**For Debian based OS (apt-get)**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

**For MacPorts**

php5-mysql @5.3.8 (php, databases) - a PHP interface to MySQL databases, including the mysql, mysqli and pdo_mysql extensions

```
sudo port install php5-mysql
```