# Error processing Request: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Tags: php, magento, pdo

My magento website was OK till yesterday. I got this error "There has been an error processing your request" Suddenly. I do not know the reason. Can anyone help me? Here is detail of error I found from report folder in CPanel.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:78:
"The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded";i:1;s:2367:"
#0 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#6 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#7 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#8 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#9 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1202): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#10 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#11 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#12 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#13 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#14 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/equitera/public_html/herbalworksbysweden.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";
s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Message: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094328/message-the-pdo-extension-is-required-for-this-adapter-but-the-extension-is-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable PDO extension from your server then every think will be ok.

Comment: Thankyou so much for reply. Can you help me how to enable it?

Comment: Contact to your server provider.

Comment: Thank you you are right, I checked in CPanel for Pear Packages I could not find PDO. I have to contact with Hosting agents.

Comment: if you find my answer correct then marks my answer correct.

Comment: Enjoy magento Coding.